# Mirth Connect: which java version to use to compile it from source?

Tags: java, build, ant, mirth

I am trying to compile mirth connect from source https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect from the 3.9.0 tag(, but also previous versions fail with he same errors)

On on hand I think it needs to be compiles with java9+ because it makes use of some javafx stuff which also the error indicates:

```
    [javac] Compiling 519 source files to /home/pwirth/code/connect/client/classes
    [javac] /home/pwirth/code/connect/client/src/com/mirth/connect/client/ui/Frame.java:54: error: cannot access Platform
    [javac] import javafx.application.Platform;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   bad class file: /home/pwirth/code/connect/client/lib/openjfx.jar(javafx/application/Platform.class)
    [javac]     class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    [javac]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

On the other hand it uses classes which are not accessible anymore since java 9 like this one:

```
    [javac]   (package com.sun.rowset is declared in module java.sql.rowset, which does not export it)
    [javac] /home/pwirth/code/connect/server/src/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/MirthCachedRowSet.java:24: error: package com.sun.rowset is not visible
    [javac] import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   (package com.sun.rowset is declared in module java.sql.rowset, which does not export it)
    [javac] /home/pwirth/code/connect/server/src/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/DatabaseConnection.java:128: error: incompatible types: MirthCachedRowSet cannot be converted to CachedRowSet
    [javac]             CachedRowSet crs = new MirthCachedRowSet();
```

I am executing `ant -f mirth-build.xml` and when running it when my `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to an java 11 also with the ant options to open the modules as described in their readme.md which declares `--add-modules=java.sql.rowset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled mirth 3.8 in the past with oracle java 8, which addresses your issues, but I had it installed from before Oracle made the licensing changes.

Depending on your usage, you can still get it from Oracle for development purposes.

That Mirth class probably should be fixed to not depend on `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` directly.

Comment: don't know why this works witht he javafx mess, but thank you, feels like I'm back in 2012 or smth ..  if you know of a complete guide anywhere let me know :)

Comment: Prior to javafx being open source, it was included with oracle java, but not openJDK.

Answer (score 4):

Got the exact same problem, but there are actually three options:

1. Compile with a Java 9+ version.  In that case open `server/build.xml`

   On line 85 it says:

   > ```
   > Uncomment the following and add additional dashes in front of the arguments to allow Java 9+
   > ```

   Do just that so it becomes:

   ```
   <compilerarg value="--add-modules" />
   <compilerarg value="java.sql.rowset,java.xml.ws" />
   <compilerarg value="--add-exports" />
   <compilerarg value="java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset=ALL-UNNAMED" />
   ```
2. Compile with a none Oracle - none Java FX JDK 8:

   Not possible.  When compiling the client it will pick-up the included `openjfx.jar` from the `client/lib` folder, which is built with JDK 10 (version 54) and will throw an error because you are building with JDK8 (version 52).
3. Use Oracle JDK 8 or Use an alternative JDK 8 with FX support.

   I compiled with success using Azul Zulu version 8.0.252.fx-zulu

   An easy way to start using different JDK's is SDKMAN!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the comment in the build.xml. I had been trying to pass the jvm args in docs/mcservice-java9+.vmoptions to the ant command itself to no avail. I am now getting stuck at test-run target with error `FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStartFailed`. Any chance you've encountered the same?

Comment: @Johan Smolders very helpfull! maybe we should create a gist or something :D

Comment: @spectorar 


I didn't get that error.  I just did:

`sdk use java 8.0.252.fx-zulu`
`cd server`
`ant -f mirth-build.xml build`

Comment: This page was added to the wiki since the question was asked. It was indicated in the Mirth Slack channel that Nextgen is in the process of migrating pages from the old wiki that are still relevant to github. They also said they will be working on updating the build script to make it more java 9+ friendly.

https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/wiki/Clone-Build-and-Run-from-Source